# Include name in buffer name and file name

Tags: buffers

Currently I am using the function `workbench`.  The function `workbench-named` introduces a name, which I want to include in
`buffer` and `file-name`.

Currently only `workbench-prefix` in being included with the command

```
(buffer (or name (concat "*" workbench-prefix "*")))
```

For instance

1. I want the buffer name to be `"*Arktika-<name>*"`, where name is
   supplied by the user when calling `workbench-named`.
2. When saving the buffer to a file, I construct a path followed by the time, then appending "-Arktika-" if name was supplied
3. When using prefix with `C-u M-x workbench`, I am asked to supply a major-mode.

Here is the implementation

```lisp
    (defvar workbench-prefix "Arktika")
    (defvar workbench-dtrek "~/wb/")
    (defvar workbench-histr nil)
    (defvar workbench-modes
      '( ("emacs-lisp-mode" . "el")
         ("lisp-mode" . "lisp")
         ("org-mode" . "org") ))
   
    (defun workbench (&optional prefix name mode)
      "Generate new temporary buffer."
      (interactive "p")
      (let* ( (buffer (or name (concat "*" workbench-prefix "*")))
              (file-name
                 (concat workbench-dtrek
                         (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%d-T%H:%M:%S--")
                         workbench-prefix "-" name ".org")) )
      (switch-to-buffer (generate-new-buffer buffer))
        (setq buffer-file-name file-name)

    (if current-prefix-arg
        (let* ( (mode (completing-read " Mode: "
                        (map-keys workbench-modes) nil t nil
                        'workbench-histr)) )
          ;; with prefix-arg, use user defined mode
          (funcall (intern mode)))
      ;; otherwise use org-mode
      (funcall (intern (or mode "org-mode"))))

        buffer-file-name))
    
    (defun workbench-named ()
      "Generate new temporary buffer by asking for buffer name."
      (interactive)
      (workbench (read-from-minibuffer " Workbench Name: ")))
```

Comment: Please be more specific. This shows a bunch of code and asks a vague question that amounts to "How can I code what I want (which isn't specified)?" And you didn't even check that the code is syntactically correct (missing `"` at end of doc string).

Comment: I cannot see where I am missing `"`.

Comment: You can't see it because I added the missing `"`. Look at the edit history.

Comment: @dilna What format do you want for the time? What happens to the buffer name if there is no name supplied (the second point indicates this is possible)? Does it matter if we visit a non-existent file first and then rename the buffer (which is considerably simpler to do) ? Please edit the question with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you expecting optional parameter `name` to be provided?

If you invoke the command interactively then `name` is `nil`, because your `interactive` spec doesn't give it a non-`nil` value.

Since `name` is `nil`, your binding for `buffer` gets the second value passed to `or`, which is `(concat "*" workbench-prefix "*")`.  That's why you're seeing only the value of `workbench-prefix`, wrapped in `*`.

And in your question you don't specify any interactive behavior you might want for `name`.  Maybe you want something like this?

```lisp
(interactive "p\ns")
```

Beyond that, you pass the **numeric** prefix arg (which is `1` by default) as parameter `prefix`, and you never even use `prefix` in your code!

Maybe you want to remove parameter `prefix` and use only `name`? Maybe you want to use `s` and not `p` in the `interactive` spec?

It's *impossible to guess what you're really wanting to do*, so it's unlikely to be able to guess what answer might help you.  (Please try to pose clearer questions.)

Comment: I only put it so I can use `(if current-prefix-arg`.  Prefix is used to activate `completing-read` so that I can select a major-mode for the buffer.  It would help on simplifying the implementation.

Comment: No idea what you're saying. You don't use `current-prefix-arg` in your code. And as I said, arg `prefix` is unused (and is `1`, the **numeric** prefix value). And arg `name` is useless in your code: it's always `nil` and that's ignored by `concat`.

Comment: I added tho part that uses `current-prefix-arg`.  You see a better way to set the mode?  Cannot see how the arg `name` in not used when calling `workbench-named`.

Comment: No idea what you're doing, sorry. Your code doesn't ever bind or set argument `name`, so it's always nil (default for an optional arg). And your code doesn't make use of function `workbench-named`.

Comment: Am just making named buffer using a major mode.  Which I can save with a filename that includes the date.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few adjustments; here's the core logic. Whatever is not right should just be a tiny detail that can be adjusted independently of the answer itself. For instance, `dilna-workbench` is no longer an interactive function because it doesn't make sense for it to be interactive; obviously the `dilna-named-workbench` is the user entry point.

As such, `dilna-named-workbench` now takes the optional prefix argument. Called without a prefix argument, it'll prompt the user for a name for the buffer. Called with the prefix, it'll ask for a name and a major mode.

The function `dilna-workbench` generates a string version of the timestamp, finds the appropriate path and filename based on the workbench prefix and workbench path, visits that file, then renames the buffer as specified in the question.

Note the helper function `dilna-path-join` which I stole from the `f` library: https://github.com/rejeep/f.el . Necessary because we must handle both relative and absolute paths.

```lisp
(defvar dilna-workbench-prefix "Arktika")
(defvar dilna-workbench-path "/tmp")

(defun dilna-path-join (&rest args)
  "Join ARGS to a single path.
Stolen and inlined from the `f' library, highly recommended."
  (let (path (relative (not (file-name-absolute-p (car args)))))
    (mapcar
     (lambda (arg) (setq path (expand-file-name arg path)))
     args)
    (if relative (file-relative-name path) path)))

(defun dilna-workbench (name &optional mode)
  "Creates and visits a new workbench file and gives the buffer a custom NAME.
Optionally set majode mode to MODE, provided as a string."
  (let* ((time (format-time-string "%F-%T"))
         (filename (string-join `(,time ,dilna-workbench-prefix ,name) "-"))
         (path (dilna-path-join dilna-workbench-path filename)))
    (find-file path)
    (rename-buffer (format "*%s-%s*" dilna-workbench-prefix name))
    (when mode (funcall (intern mode)))))

(defun dilna-named-workbench (&optional prefix)
  "Ask user for a name and create a new workbench file from that name.
If PREFIX is non-nil, ask the user for a major-mode and set new buffer to
that mode."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((name (read-from-minibuffer "Workbench name: "))
        (mode (when prefix (read-from-minibuffer "Major mode: "))))
    (dilna-workbench name mode)))
```

Comment: @dilna if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.